# Why Can't I Set Env Variables By Running A BASH Script From An Npm Script?

Tags: bash, npm, npm-scripts

I have a nodejs javascript project, but I would like to set a bunch of environment variables locally.  created a bash file that just exports some variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export waka=flaka
export fat=booty
```

When I use the dot to source and run the file from the command line it works fine:

```
. ./env.sh
```

And I can see the variable has been set

```
echo $waka  # prints "flaka"
```

But then I try to take this command and make it an npm script by adding it to my package.json

```
scripts: {
  "set-env": ". ./env.sh",
  ...
 }
```

and then run it:

```
npm run set-env
```

The script is run but the environment variables are not saved:

```
echo $waka  # prints undefined (assuming you didn't already run it from command line)
```

So, I'm wondering why it doesn't save the envrionment variables as an npm script and if it's possible to run the bash script from an npm script in a way such that the environment variables will be saved for the rest of the command prompt session. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`npm` is not a shell command; it runs in a separate process that forks *another* shell in order to run the command specified by `set-env`. `env.sh` is executed, but then that shell immediately exits, at which point the changes are gone (and then `npm` itself exits).

Comment: thanks, but are you sure it is not possible to have it affect the current shell process?

Comment: Yes; it is a fundamental concept that the environment of a process cannot be modified by one of its children.